# group by first twelve months only

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions

I have a query that pulls transaction data, by different account. I want to only pull in the first 12 months of the trailing transaction by sale. For Example - the two records wouldnt pull because they fall out of the twelve month window since the first transaction date. how would i write a query like this? any help if very much appreciated!

```
Account Date
Apples  1/1/2022
Apples  5/1/2022
Apples  8/1/2022
Apples  9/1/2022
Apples  12/1/2022
--Apples    1/1/2023
--Apples    7/1/2023
Bananas 5/1/2022
Bananas 6/1/2022
Bananas 7/1/2022
Bananas 12/1/2022
Oranges 1/1/2023
Oranges 2/1/2023
Oranges 3/1/2023
Oranges 4/1/2023
```

Comment: the two apples 1/1/2023 and 7/1/2023 should be excluded*

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result. (It's a good idea to simplify, perhaps three or four months is enough to illustrate the problem - a [mcve].)

Comment: Orange too must be excluded if I understand well...

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply and efficiently with window functions:

```
select account, date
from (
    select t.*, min(date) over(partition by account) as min_date
    from mytable t
) t
where date < min_date + interval '1' year
```

The idea is to compute the earliest date of each account with a window `min()`. We can then use this information to filter the dataset.

You did not tag which database you are running. The syntax for date arithmetics does vary with database engines: the above is standard ANSI SQL, which you might need to adapt to your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on PostgreSQL :

```
create table testdata (Account varchar(50), thedate date);
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2022/1/1');
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2022/5/1');
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2022/8/1');
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2022/9/1');
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2022/12/1');
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2023/1/1');
insert into testdata values ('Apples',  '2023/7/1');
insert into testdata values ('Bananas', '2022/5/1');
insert into testdata values ('Bananas', '2022/6/1');
insert into testdata values ('Bananas', '2022/7/1');
insert into testdata values ('Bananas', '2022/12/1');
insert into testdata values ('Oranges', '2023/1/1');
insert into testdata values ('Oranges', '2023/2/1');
insert into testdata values ('Oranges', '2023/3/1');
insert into testdata values ('Oranges', '2023/4/1');

select * from testdata;

 account |  thedate
---------+------------
 Apples  | 2022-01-01
 Apples  | 2022-05-01
 Apples  | 2022-08-01
 Apples  | 2022-09-01
 Apples  | 2022-12-01
 Apples  | 2023-01-01
 Apples  | 2023-07-01
 Bananas | 2022-05-01
 Bananas | 2022-06-01
 Bananas | 2022-07-01
 Bananas | 2022-12-01
 Oranges | 2023-01-01
 Oranges | 2023-02-01
 Oranges | 2023-03-01
 Oranges | 2023-04-01
```

And now the query :

```
select * from testdata
where thedate < (select min(thedate) + INTERVAL '12 months'
                 from testdata);

 account |  thedate   
---------+------------
 Apples  | 2022-01-01
 Apples  | 2022-05-01
 Apples  | 2022-08-01
 Apples  | 2022-09-01
 Apples  | 2022-12-01
 Bananas | 2022-05-01
 Bananas | 2022-06-01
 Bananas | 2022-07-01
 Bananas | 2022-12-01
```